# Can we rotate the x-axis and y-axis in a Seaborn Pairplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I'm trying to rotate the x-axis and y-axis in a Seaborn Pairplot. SO far all I can rotate is the tick-params. I really want to rotate the x-axis and y-axis 45 degrees. Can we do that???

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g=sns.pairplot(penguins)

for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    ax.tick_params(rotation = 45)
```

[image]

Comment: **I really want to rotate the x-axis and y-axis 45 degrees.** What you want, is not clear.

Comment: On the x-axis, the 'bill_length_mm' is horizontal. I want to rotate it 45 degrees, like the 'tick_params' is rotated 45 degrees. Similarly, on the y-axis, the 'body_mass_g' is vertical. I want to rotate it 45 degrees.

Comment: Those are called x/y axis labels. When referring to the x/y axis, that’s a separate component of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more testing, I finally got this to work.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g=sns.pairplot(penguins)


g = sns.pairplot(penguins, kind="scatter")
for ax in g.axes.flatten():
    # rotate x axis labels
    ax.set_xlabel(ax.get_xlabel(), rotation = 45)
    # rotate y axis labels
    ax.set_ylabel(ax.get_ylabel(), rotation = 45)
    # set y labels alignment
    ax.yaxis.get_label().set_horizontalalignment('right')
```

[image]